# Understanding JavaScript this with private function and self executing function

Tags: javascript, scope, execute-immediate, private-functions

I was reading Angus Croll [understanding JS this](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/) blog and found this

```
var a = {
  b: function() {
    var c = function() {
      return this;
    };
    return c();
  }
}; 

a.b();//window
```

To me it looks like, at the time of invoking c, c was inside b. that should be the invoking context (correct me, if i am wrong). when it executes, Why context(this) of c() is window?

there is another example i found in that [blog](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/)

```
var a = {
  b: function() {
    return (function() {return this;})();
  }
};

a.b(); //window
```

why context of b is window? Does anonymous function always run in the global context?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good way to understand `this` (pun intended):

The value of `this` inside a function is determined by the way the function is called. With one exception, it doesn't have to do with where the function is defined, what other functions it may be nested inside, what object it was defined as part of, what kind of function it is, or any of that.

When you call a function using a method call like `foo.bar()` or `foo[bar]()`, `this` inside the function is the `foo` object.

When you call a function with an ordinary function call like `foo()`, `this` in the function is the `window` object, or if the function uses strict mode it is `undefined`.

That's the one exception - if the function itself or its surrounding code has `"use strict";` it changes `this` for a plain function call. For good code that shouldn't make a difference - you shouldn't be writing code that depends on `this` being the `window` object anyway.

Otherwise, what you care about is what object `this` refers to in a method call. And that's always determined by how the function is *called*, not how it's defined.

Let's go through your first example.

When you call `a.b()`, you're calling `b` as a method of the `a` object. So inside the `b` function, `this` is the same as `a`.

As it happens, it doesn't do us any good to know that, because the `b` function never does anything with `this`. All it does is call `c()` as an ordinary function. So inside `c`, `this` is the `window` object, or it would be `undefined` if you were in strict mode.

The `c` function simply returns its `this` value, or `window`. And that is also the return value from `b`. So that's why you see `window` as the result: it all comes from how the code calls the `b` and `c` functions.

Now about the second example: well, that's just terribly obfuscated code, isn't it? Who would ever write this code and expect anyone to understand it at first glance?

So let's turn it into a more readable form. This line is the problem:

```
    return (function() {return this;})();
```

Let's take out the parenthesized function expression:

```
    (function() {return this;})
```

and assign it to a temp variable:

```
    var temp = (function() {return this;});
```

We don't need the extra parentheses any more, and let's indent the code for readability:

```
    var temp = function() {
        return this;
    };
```

and we can call that `temp` variable as a function in the `return` statement:

```
    return temp();
```

Now we can put this back into the `b` function in the code example:

```
var a = {
  b: function() {
    var temp = function() {
        return this;
    };
    return temp();
  }
};

a.b(); //window
```

Hey! Doesn't that code look familiar? In fact, it's identical to the first example except for the name of the `temp` variable. So now you see why it works the same as the first one.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could u be able to explain little more? For the private function (inside function) where i just create and call. How the global context come into the picture.

Answer (score 1):

One key to look for is the `new` keyword, which establishes a new context. Don't see a `new`? Then the context hasn't changed, which means `this` hasn't changed. If you called this from within `window`, then that's your context, and that's your `this`. (This changes if you use `call()` or `apply()` with a scope, but that obviously doesn't apply here.)